# Firebase Analytics: Event Parameters not Logged on FB Console

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have events successfully being logged to the Firebase console however **their associated parameters are not being shown**.

My goal is to track which products and brands in my app are getting clicked on most. With the debug view I can see the view_item events being triggered and the parameters being successfully passed however in the console I cannot see the parameters such as in the demo project's level completed section. I'm using swift 4 for iOS on the simulator and on my iPhone X.

I have the parameters enabled by clicking the 3-dots in the event window and enabling them however after 48 hours I see the events being logged, but no parameters attached.

Here is where I log the events:

```
Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventAddToCart, parameters: [AnalyticsParameterItemName : name, AnalyticsParameterPrice : price, AnalyticsParameterItemBrand : seller, AnalyticsParameterCurrency : "€"])
```

[Parameters enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CD14C.png) and 
[No parameter data being shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnZ5C.png)

Have I logged it incorrectly or am I doing something wrong on the console side of things? Much apprecited, Allen <3

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday for Xcode reasons I uninstalled and reinstalled the app on my device and that seems to have worked! Didn't change any code.